# I Have Issues Installing Basemap

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model, databases, image-preprocessing

*I tried to install **Basemap** and it gives me this:*

preparing transaction: done

verifying transaction: done

executing transaction: **failed**

**ERROR** conda.core.link:_execute(507): An error occurred while uninstalling packag

e 'defaults::conda-4.5.12-py37_0'.

**PermissionError (13, Access is denied)**

Attempting to roll back

Rolling back transaction: done

**PermissionError (13, Access is denied)**

***Question***: What should I do next? I will appreciate your response as I have been on this for some time now.

*Thanks.*

***NOTE:*** I have also tried to install cartopy but I ran into the same problem.

***NOTE:*** I use Windows 7 32 bits. I use python 3.7.1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about [Basemap Matplotlib Toolkit](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html), you have to manually download the [Windows binary installers](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/releases/).